# Showing that a polynomial is zero given that a sum containing its coefficients sum to zero

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

I've been trying to solve this exam question on an exam in real analysis. Thus, only such methods may be used. The problem is as follows.

> Assume that $c_0,c_1,\dots,c_n$ are real numbers so that $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{c_k}{k+1}=0.$$ Prove that the polynomial $$p(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}c_kx^k$$ has a zero in $[0,1]$.

I have played around with shorter samples of the sum to see how it works to give us coefficients with the desired properties, but I don't really have any clue as of how to prove it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** Define$$q(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{c_kx^{k+1}}{k+1}.$$What is $q(0)$? And $q(1)$? How are $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ related?

Comment: Here, $q(0)=0$ and $q(1)$ is just the first sum in my question. I'm not quite sure how they are related.

Comment: @OskarTegby What is $q'(x)$?

Comment: Ah! It's $p(x)$, but why is that important?

Comment: @OskarTegby Because, since $q(0)=q(1)=0$, then $q'(c)=0$ for some $c\in(0,1)$…

Comment: Why is this a question on a real analysis exam? It just seems like some math trick to me.

Comment: @OskarTegby Because it uses Rolle's theorem.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @OskarTegby I'm glad I could help.